# Make Tailwind headings and typography responsive

Tags: tailwind-css

I want to make my headings `h1, h2, h3` etc responsive. I thought I could do something like:

```
h1 {
@apply text-lg lg:text-2xl xl:text-3xl;
}
```

But then I get an error.

How do I solve this best?

Comment: this should work fine as per the documentation for [@apply](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#apply). perhaps the problem was with your dev configuration, but I don't know what error you got

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### UPDATE:

This question was asked when Tailwind 1.2 was in use. Since version 1.7 Tailwind supports pseudo classes in @apply directive. In first it was experimental feature that had to be turned on manually in config, but currently it is normal functionality.

So code from question will work just fine.

Source: https://blog.tailwindcss.com/tailwindcss-1-7

<s>Unfortunately you cannot do it that way:---</s>

From tailwind docs:

> It's important to understand that @apply will not work for inlining pseudo-class or responsive variants of another utility. Instead, apply the plain version of that utility into the appropriate pseudo-selector or a new media query

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives/

Instead you have @screen for this. So in your case it will be.

```
h1 {
   @apply text-lg;

   @screen lg {
      @apply text-2xl;
   }

   @screen xl {
      @apply text-3xl;
   }
}
```

Or

```
h1 {
   @apply text-lg;
}

@screen lg {
   h1 {
      @apply text-2xl;
   }
}

@screen xl {
   h1 {
      @apply text-3xl;
   }
}
```

Comment: great thanks. I will except your answer. And do you know how to add/use pseudo elements `:before` and `:after` to e.g. a `<li> in Tailwind?

Comment: There is no before/after prefixes in Tailwind. You can add this on your own or use plugin like "yutahaga/tailwindcss-pseudo-elements" but I have ben using tailwind for a long time and never had this need. I do not see reason why not type this in "normal" css ;) Just xxx:before { content: "", @apply tailwind-classes-here }

Comment: the documentation for [@apply](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#apply) shows the use of pseudo-variants and I've also been using them this way. OP should be able to use the code in their example.

Comment: @Zach this question was asked 8 months ago ;) Not a issue anymore